# passing values from javascript to jsp using jquery

Tags: jquery, jsp

I have a jsp page that submits a form asynchronously using jQuery.ajax(). After successful submission the server returns a json object . 
Now what I need to do is open a dialog box and display the values in the columns in a table.

I have a div in my jsp representing my dialog box. Now What I am not able to achieve over here is  that I am not able to somehow set these column values from the javascript.

I tried adding a hidden variable in the jsp for each column and then setting this variable in the js but it didn't work.

```
jquery("#data").val("test")
```

my html code

Success!!: val





val1
 


val2Ticket Created:

Now over here I need to populate the table column values and the values after success! with the json object that i retrieve from the json object returned by the ajax request. I have verified that the data is correctly retrieved.
Any solutions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the HTML that you want to change?

Comment: If you'll post an example of what you've already got, we can help you fill in the details you're missing.

Comment: mentioned below is my html code

Comment: @sid , what #data , is it the input type id ??

Comment: Not nearly enough information to help.  Your code you've shown has nothing to do with the table you want to populate.  How is the table built?  Edit your Question and add a lot more detail. Don't post code in comments.

Comment: @sid , you should access each element in div modal , and then set using jquerys $('').text(); , if you are getting the json back , make a index based solution..

Comment: @Sid: it's a bit much to ask us to re-create the entire page (which you say you've already got mostly working), just just to show you how to loop over the JSON results and generate a table.  Would you mind editing your post to include the actual javascript you're using to send the ajax request and handle the result?

Comment: @sid , whatever lee suggested is good, if you want store the json object in a global variable , but you should do everything in the ajax success.

Comment: Please ignore my previous comments.                                                             <div id="dialogsuccess" title="Result">
<div class="dialog-ob-block">


<div class="2"><div class="dialog-text-success1">Success </div><div class="dialog-text-success2">val to be displayed fromjs</div></div>
</div>
class="1">
<tr>
<td >val1:</td>
<td>USD   1000.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>val2:</td>

<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td class=""> 000000000</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

Comment: @sid , just a suggestion don't use numbers as class names or ids ,its not allowed, it can result in weird results.

Comment: yes thats a sample code. the actual html has names instead of numbers

Comment: @sid: please *edit your post*, and put your code examples in there.  When you put code examples in the comments, it's nearly impossible for the rest of us to read.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using json objects as such but here is how I do a partial postback in jsp.

JavaScript

```
var data = {"Ns":Ns, queryString: $('#hdnQueryString').val()};
var success = successSelectSortOrder;
var errorFunction = genericError;
genericPostback("post", hostPath + "ctrlSort.jsp", data,success,errorFunction);

function genericPostback(postbackType,url, data,success,errFunction)
        {
            $.ajax(
                {

                    type : "post",
                    url  : url,
                    data : data,
                    success:success,
                    error :errFunction
                }
            )
        }

        function successSelectSortOrder(msg)
        {
          //do something with the msg here.  
          //generally i have returned html and if not then xml
          //i use jquery to pull it apart from here
        }
```

Then my jsp page;

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%
    out.print("My returned html or data here");
%>
```